# Update nodejs in cygwin

Tags: node.js, bash, cygwin

Sometime back I've installed nodejs via cygwin which shows me the version 0.4.12 when I do node -v in bash. 
Recently I've installed nodejs with the window installer which shows me the version 0.10.20 in window command prompt.

My Problem is I'm using Claymate for GumbyFramework in cygwin and it requires nodejs version above 0.8.0. How can I update the Nodejs in cygwin to the latest version?

Btw I'm using Windows Vista OS.

Pls. help!! Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Create a VirtualBox VM with your favorite Linux distribution and do whatever you need to do in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please know that Cygwin is not a supported platform. There would be a node version which would break things for you. The latest version that compiles natively on Cygwin is 0.4.12. Though the [wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) page mentions some people had success building Node.js 0.10 on MinGW+MSYS. Try the following instructions : http://opensourcepack.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/nodejs-with-posix-path-support.html

Comment: Thank you!! That cleared my doubts. will find ways to work with it.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't mess with compile on Windows.  You may want to just replace the old version Node.exe file with the newer Node.exe file on disk.  You should be able to find the Cygwin folders within Windows explorer.  You can search the entire disk, in windows not cygwin, for the file name node.exe.   You should see the node.exe windows is finding, and the one cygwin is finding, under the cygwin folders.

Rename the cygwin node.exe and copy in the newer node.exe.   Now, you nay get an issue with npm, in which case you may want to try the same thing with the npm folder.

I know cygwin isnt officially supported, but when you get it installed correctly it works.

Comment: This gives an error message when attempting to run node after replacing the binary.

--- 
net.js:156
    this._handle.open(options.fd);
                ^
Error: EINVAL, invalid argument

Comment: Windows node does *not* work correctly under cygwin.  Node processes are not able to function correctly under the mintty terminal emulator that cygwin uses.  See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006